# How to return products for subcategories of category in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to return products of categories. When i click on clothes i want to return products of T-shirt category, jacket category and so on. I made it like nested categories
This is Model for Categories

```
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [ForeignKey("parentID")]
        public Kategorija parentCategory { get; set; }
        public List<Kategorija> Subcategories { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<Proizvod> Proizvodi { get; set; }
```

I return categories to show them in angular like this

```
[Route("PreuzmiKategorije")]
        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<ActionResult> preuzmiKategorije()
        {
            try
            {
                var kategorije = await Context.Kategorijas.Include(c => c.Subcategories).ToListAsync();
                List<Kategorija> result = new List<Kategorija>();
                List<Kategorija> Rez = new List<Kategorija>();
                HashSet<int> processedCategoryIds = new HashSet<int>();

                foreach (var category in kategorije)
                {
                    if (!processedCategoryIds.Contains(category.Id))
                    {
                        result.Add(category);
                        processedCategoryIds.Add(category.Id);

                        AddSubcategoriesRecursive(category.Subcategories, result, processedCategoryIds);
                    }
                }

                foreach(var res in result)
                {
                    if(res.parentCategory == null)
                    {
                        Rez.Add(res);
                    }
                }
                return Ok(Rez);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
        private void AddSubcategoriesRecursive(IEnumerable<Kategorija> subcategories, List<Kategorija> result, HashSet<int> processedCategoryIds)
        {
            foreach (var subcategory in subcategories)
            {
                if (!processedCategoryIds.Contains(subcategory.Id))
                {
                    result.Add(subcategory);
                    processedCategoryIds.Add(subcategory.Id);

                    AddSubcategoriesRecursive(subcategory.Subcategories, result, processedCategoryIds);
                }
            }
        }
```

How to return products based on this function?

I tried something like this but it dont work fine.

```
[Route("PreuzmiProizvodePodkategorija")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PreuzmiProizvodePodkategorija(string kategorija)
        {
            try
            {
                var kategorijaZaPretragu = await context.Kategorijas
                    .Include(c => c.Subcategories)
                    .Include(c => c.Proizvodi)
                    .Where(c => c.Name == kategorija).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                if (kategorijaZaPretragu == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                var proizvodi = new List<Proizvod>();
                DodajProizvodePodkategorija(kategorijaZaPretragu.Subcategories, proizvodi);

                return Ok(proizvodi);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DodajProizvodePodkategorija(IEnumerable<Kategorija> subkategorije, List<Proizvod> proizvodi)
        {
            foreach (var subkategorija in subkategorije)
            {
                proizvodi.AddRange(subkategorija.Proizvodi);

                DodajProizvodePodkategorija(subkategorija.Subcategories, proizvodi);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getProductsViaCategory/{category}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> getProductsViaCategory(string category)
        {
            try
            {
                var kategorija = context.Kategorijas
                                        .Include(p => p.Subcategories)
                                        .Include(p => p.Proizvodi)
                                        .ThenInclude(p => p.ProfilKorisnika)
                                        .Where(k => k.Name == category).FirstOrDefault();
                if (kategorija == null)
                    return BadRequest("Kategorija ne postoji");

                List<Proizvod> products = new List<Proizvod>();
                if(kategorija.Proizvodi != null)
                    products.AddRange(kategorija.Proizvodi);
                AddProductRecursive(kategorija, products);

                return Ok(products.Select(p => new
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    ImageUrl = GetImage(p.ProfilKorisnika.Email, p.Id).Split("|"),
                    Naziv = p.Naziv,
                    Mesto = p.Mesto,
                    Status = p.status,
                    Username = p.ProfilKorisnika.Username,
                    Email = p.ProfilKorisnika.Email
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
        private void AddProductRecursive(Kategorija category, List<Proizvod> products)
        {
                if(category.Subcategories != null)
                    foreach (var sub in category.Subcategories)
                    {
                    var kategorija = context.Kategorijas
                                            .Include(q => q.Subcategories)
                                            .Include(q => q.Proizvodi)
                                            .ThenInclude(p => p.ProfilKorisnika)
                                            .Where(q => q.Id == sub.Id)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
                        if (kategorija.Proizvodi != null)
                            products.AddRange(kategorija.Proizvodi);
                        AddProductRecursive(kategorija, products);
                    }
        }
```

This work for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).